# How to include same formBuilder object in multiple components?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular2-formbuilder

I built a form Builder object and want include it in several other components. Is it possible to build one and include it in other components using service or by any other means? My object is huge and including it in other components makes the TS file lengthy. I want to reduce the size of TS file. My fb object;

```
    `export class ApplicationComponent implements OnInit {

     applicationForm: FormGroup;
     constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private route:Router, private activRoute:ActivatedRoute,
    private _ser: ApiServiceService) { 
    this.applicationForm = this.fb.group({
    //Application
      "IsNew": ['1'],
      "StudentID": ['', Validators.required,],
      "StudInfoID": [''],
      "UniversityID": [''],    // ?            
      "UniversityName": [''],  // ?      
      "CountryCode": [''],     // ?
      "DateOfApplication": ['', Validators.required,],
      "FirstName": [''],
      "MiddleName": [''],       // default null         
      "LastName": [''],
      "ApplicationStatusID": [''],    // ?           
      "Gender": [''],
      "DateOfBirth": [''],

    //personal Details                
      "PlaceOfBirth": [''],
      //Contact Details
      "EmailID": [''],
      "Handphone": [''],
      "Telephone": [''],
      "EmergencyContactName": [''],
      "EmergencyContactRelationShip": [''],
      "EmergencyContactTelephone": [''],
      //Address Details
      //Permanant Address
      "PermanentAddressCountryCode": [''],
      "permanentAddressState": [''],
      "PermanentAddressCity": [''],
      "PermanentAddress": [''],
      "PermanentAddressPostalCode": [''],
      //Mailing Address
      "MailingAddressCountryCode": [''],
      "MailingAddressState": [''],
      "MailingAddressCity": [''],
      "MailingAddress": [''],
      "MailingAddressPostalCode": [''],
      //Passport Details
      "PassportNumber": [''],
      "PassportIssueDate": [''],
      "PassportExpiryDate": [''],

    //Parent Details
      //Father Details
      "FatherFullName": [''],
      "FatherCitizenShip": [''],
      "FatherOccupation": [''],
      "FatherAddress": [''],
      "FatherPostalCode": [''],
      "FatherOfficeTelephone": [''],
      "FatherHomeTelephone": [''],
      "FatherHandPhone": [''],
      "FatherFaxNumber": [''],
      "FatherEmail": [''],
      //Mother Details             
      "MotherFullName": [''],
      "MotherCitizenShip": [''],
      "MotherOccupation": [''],
      "MotherAddress": [''],
      "MotherPostalCode": [''],
      "MotherOfficeTelephone": [''],
      "MotherHomeTelephone": [''],
      "MotherHandPhone": [''],
      "MotherFaxNumber": [''],
      "MotherEmail": [''],
      //Guardian Details
      "GuardianFullName": [''],
      "GuardianCitizenShip": [''],
      "GuardianOccupation": [''],
      "GuardianAddress": [''],
      "GuardianPostalCode": [''],
      "GuardianOfficeTelephone": [''],
      "GuardianHomeTelephone": [''],
      "GuardianHandPhone": [''],
      "GuardianFaxNumber": [''],
      "GuardianEmail": [''],

    //security questions
      "FirstSchoolName": [''],
      "MotherMedianName": [''],
      "FavoriteFood": [''],
      "FavoriteHoliday": [''],

    //medical disability needs
      "ChkmedicalconditionwhichmayaffectyourstudiesYes": [''],
      "ChkmedicalconditionwhichmayaffectyourstudiesNo": [''],
      "ChkHearing": [''],
      "ChkMedical": [''],
      "ChkVision": [''],
      "ChkMobility": [''],
      "ChkOther": [''],
      "Other": [''],
      "ChkWhatCICY": [''],
      "ChkWhatCICN": [''],

    //other Info
      "NationalServiceStatus": [''],
      "ORDDate": [''],
      "ExemptedReason": [''],
      "SpecialSkill": [''],
      "SpecialSkillExplain": [''],
      "ArrestedByPolice": [''],
      "ArrestedBypoliceExplain": [''],
      "DismissedFromEmployment": [''],
      "DismissedFromEmploymentExplain": [''],
      "MedicalCondition": [''],
      "MedicalConditionExplain": [''],
      "SubjectToSanction": [''],
      "SubjectToSanctionExplain": [''],
      "KnowAtSunrice": [''],
      "Source": [''],
      //co-curricular activities
      "DetailsOfECAMemberShip": [''],
      //English Language Proficiency
      "ChkEngLangFirstLanguageYes": [''],
      "ChkEngLangFirstLanguageNo": [''],
      "ChkIELTS": [''],
      "ChkTofel": [''],
      "ChkCute": [''],
      "ChkOtherEngLang": [''],
      "ChkGCEO": [''],
      "EngScoreGrade": [''],
      //sponsor details
      "ChktutionfeePaidByOrganisationY": [''],
      "ChktutionfeePaidByOrganisationN": [''],
      "OrganisationName": [''],
      "Status": [''],

    //Documents Required
      "ChkSPM": [''],
      "ChkALevelResult": [''],
      "ChkALevelCert": [''],
      "ChkDegreeResult": [''],
      "ChkDegreeCert": [''],
      "ChkPassportCopy": [''],
      "ChkReferenceLetter": [''],
      "ChkPersonalStatement": [''],
      "ChkIELTSResult": [''],
      "ChkCV": [''],
      "ChkPortfolio": [''],
      "ChkchkOthers": [''],

    // '?'               
      "DocumentsOthers": [''],
      "CreatedBy": [''],
      "UpdatedBy": [''],
      "CreatedDate": [''],
      "ModifiedDate": [''],
      "ApplicationNumber": [''],

    //new field 'parent-details'
      "fathersector": [''],
      "Mothersector": [''],
      "Gardiansector": [''],

    //for counselor '?'
      "EmpCode": [''],
      "Counsellor": ['', 
   [Validators.required,]],
      "CounsellorMobileNo": [''],

    //Children Details
      "FullName1": [''],
      "Ctizenship1": [''],
      "sex1": [''],
      "DateOfBirth1": [''],
      "countryofBirth1": [''],
      "placeofbirth1": [''],
      "FullName2": [''],
      "Ctizenship2": [''],
      "sex2": [''],
      "DateOfBirth2": [''],
      "countryofBirth2": [''],
      "placeofbirth2": [''],
      "FullName3": [''],
      "Ctizenship3": [''],
      "sex3": [''],
      "DateOfBirth3": [''],
      "countryofBirth3": [''],
      "placeofbirth3": [''],
      "FullName4": [''],
      "Ctizenship4": [''],
      "sex4": [''],
      "DateOfBirth4": [''],
      "countryofBirth4": [''],
      "placeofbirth4": [''],
      "FullName5": [''],
      "Ctizenship5": [''],
      "sex5": [''],
      "DateOfBirth5": [''],
      "countryofBirth5": [''],
      "placeofbirth5": [''],
      "FullName6": [''],
      "Ctizenship6": [''],
      "sex6": [''],
      "DateOfBirth6": [''],
      "countryofBirth6": [''],
      "placeofbirth6": [''],
      "Identity": [''],

    //Documents for under 18
      "chkguardianslip": [''],
      "chkhomestay": [''],
      "chkapprovedhostelaccomodation": [''],
      "chkwelfareform": [''],
      "chkCAAW": [''],
      "chkform1223": [''],
      "chkstudent": [''],
      "chkfather": [''],
      "chkmother": [''],
      "chkcourtletter": [''],
      "chkdeceasedletter": [''],
      "chkstudbirthcertificate": [''],
      "chkoyher1": [''],
      "txtother1": [''],

    // personal details
      "MaillingAddSameAsPermanat": [''], 
    //Address details

    //Application 
      "IC_No": ['', [Validators.required,]],
      "Counsellor2": [''],
      "EmpCode2": [''],
      "Counsellor3": [''],
      "EmpCode3": [''],

    // '?'
      "RejectedStatusRemarks": [''] 
    });
  }`
```

I want to include this object in 8 more components. Is there any way to write this object somewhere else and include in all components?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is a `FormGroup` configuration you can reuse multiple times.
I didn't try it, but I guess you can define an object in a separate .ts file, e.g.

```
export formConfig: {[key: string]: any} = {

    //Application
      "IsNew": ['1'],
      "StudentID": ['', Validators.required,],
      "StudInfoID": [''],
      "UniversityID": [''],    // ?            
...
}
```

and then import that object in your `Component` and feed it to `FormBuilder`'s .group method.

Comment: I got the object in console, however getting error, Cannot find control with name: '.....all formControlNames'

Comment: I created a separate ts file, and imported the object into component. I included the object in formgroup declaration....this.applicationForm = this.fb.group({ FormConfig )}. I am getting errors as mentioned in above comment. I got the whole object in console when I did console.log(FormConfig); in constructor.

Comment: this.applicationForm = this.fb.group(formConfig) <- notice no braces

Comment: I included braces; this.applicationForm = this.fb.group({formConfig}); still getting error.

Comment: I think the entire object must be present in ts file whenever we are using formControlName in form input elements. It will be great if to get a way to use reusable object compatible with formControlName.